# Flutter invertColor is not inverting colors in phone

Tags: dart, flutter

Here is the code, and it isn't working the way it should be.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  MediaQueryData mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);

  print("old = ${mediaQuery.invertColors}"); // shows false (OK)
  mediaQuery.copyWith(invertColors: true); // changing the value
  print("new = ${mediaQuery.invertColors}"); // shows false (not OK)

  return Container();
}
```

How can I invert colors at runtime? I am using iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The `copyWith` method creates a new instance. To achieve what you want, you should wrap your children in a new `MediaQuery` widget like this and use the edited `MediaQueryData` with the `invertColors` changed:

```
return MediaQuery(
   data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(invertColors: true),
   child: ...,
);
```

Comment: I am not sure why this isn't working. The colors remains the same. However if I use `boldText`, it does work. Seems like it isn't possible to do so...? Is that working in your phone? Till then I am upvoting it.

Comment: And how do I change the property of `MediaQuery` at runtime?